# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the services

Tags: node.js, nestjs

When I used person Service in the Organisation Service, I got the error like this:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PersonService (PersonModel, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the OrganizationModule context.

Organization.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class OrganizationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Organization') private readonly organizationModel: Model<Organization>,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UsersService))
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly mailerService: MailerService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => PersonService))
    private readonly personService: PersonService,
  ) {}
```

Organization.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RateLimiterModule.register({ type: 'Memory', points: 100, duration: 60 * 5, keyPrefix: 'organization'  }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([ 
      { name: 'Organization', schema: OrganizationSchema },
      { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema },
      { name: 'Person', schema: PersonSchema },
    ]),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt', session: false }),
    forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
    forwardRef(() => PersonModule),
  ],
  exports: [OrganizationService],
  controllers: [OrganizationController],
  providers: [OrganizationService, UsersService, PersonService]
})
```

Person.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RateLimiterModule.register({ type: 'Memory', points: 100, duration: 60 * 5 }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'Person', schema: PersonSchema },
      { name: 'User', schema: UserSchema },
    ]),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt', session: false }),
    forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
  ],
  exports: [PersonService],
  controllers: [PersonController],
  providers: [PersonService, UsersService]
})
export class PersonModule {

  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
     consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
      .forRoutes(PersonController);

      consumer
       .apply(SiteMiddleware)
       .forRoutes(PersonController);
   }

}
```

What is the error in this code?

Comment: show PersonService

Comment: export class PersonService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Person') private readonly personModel: Model<Person>,
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

Comment: did you really have `Injectable()` instead of `@Injectable()` or it was a typo here?

Comment: I have used @Injectable(). I just correct here

Comment: Do you have `@Injectable()` decorator on `PersonService` and `UsersService`?

Comment: @PavloNaumenko Yes

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't re-add dependencies to `providers` arrays. You already define the `PersonService` provider in the `PersonModule`, and the `PersonModule` properly `exports` that provider, so all that needs to happen is the `OrganizationModule` needs to have `PersonModule` in the `imports`.

By putting `PersonService` in the `OrganizationModule`'s `providers`, Nest will try to recreate the provider in the context of the `OrganiztionModule`, meaning it will need access to `getModelToken('Person')` and `UsersService` as other providers in the current context.